# Google chrome extension to copy URLs from page

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions

I'm looking for an extension that copies the URLs on a page.

A FireFox add-on that does this is [Copy Link URL](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10552/).

Anyone having an idea for that?

(I know there are Google Chrome extensions to copy the URLs of the Tabs, that's not the behaviour I'm looking for).

--jeroen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Link2Clip](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fmieebpnfbcjdackmfajcbbknaikebla?hl=en).

Comment: does not work on **https** sites